# Eclipse Luna Unable to Save Preferences

Tags: eclipse, preferences

Using Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) -- with the CDT bundle as a base -- with most packages installed using pacman/yaourt under `/usr`, I am unable to persistently save a few preferences relating to appearance. Though most of the preferences I have set seem to stay over restarts; two only work during one run of eclipse:
    - `General/Appearance/ColorTheme/SetAllBackgroundColorsToTheDefault`
    - `General/Editors/TextEditors/Annotations/*`

Oddly, the first listed setting shows in the preferences window as set the way I chose; however, eclipse seems to simply ignore it unless I go in and toggle the setting, apply, toggle and reapply.

The Annotarions settings, however, work when set; but on restart, the preferences window show them as having been changed from what I set. It is as if the setting is never persisted to disk.

I have made sure that I own and have `u+rw` permissions on everything in `~/.eclipse`. I have also tested by moving `.eclipse` to `.eclipse_back` and running with a new user conf dir. I've also tried the `-initialize` and `-clean` switches. Nothing seems to remedy this oddness. Any guidance?

----- EDIT

I have discovered that the annotation and colortheme preferences live under `<workspace>/.metadata/`. I have verified write access to this dir tree as well. I have also tried changing:
    `warningTextStyle=DASHED_BOX`
in
    `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`
manually when no eclipse instance is running. While this setting stays persisted in the file, eclipse seems to simply ignore it. WT_?

----- EDIT 2

Manually editing `usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717/css/dark/e4-dark_preferencestyle.css` is also only partially useful. To be specific, changing `'AbstractTextEditor.Color.SelectionForeground.SystemDefault'` from false to true does indeed work as expected. Changing the annotations like `'warningHighlightingTextStyle=DASHED_BOX'` does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: As @EricWang reminded me, I **AM** using Luna, not Kepler. Edited the post to reflect reality... And called `dopeslap(self)`.

Comment: Why do you edit the theme config file directly? I use the classic theme, it works well for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had suffered a long time from the same problems with Annotations setting in Luna/Dark theme.
In `e4-dark_preferencestyle.css` you need to change `warningIndicationHighlighting=true` to `warningIndicationHighlighting=false` as well.
Afterwards, the text style options like `BOX` or `SQUIGGLES` do work as expected.

Comment: I'm crying tears of gratitude!!! Do you perchance know whether there has been a bug filed on this? If not, any guidance on how on earth to report it properly -- I can't tell where in the massive codebase this oddity lies.

Comment: I have found a bugreport for this problem including a possible solution. [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441135)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot. It was really annoying that every time I restart eclipse all the warnings were highlighted again.